# How to filter my dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

Here is my dataframe:

```
                  df1
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1   -1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1    NA   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

I'm trying to make a second dataframe, df2, to filter the rows where

```
df1$Col2<0==TRUE
```

So df2 would look like this

```
                  df2
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
1   -1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Wen's comment works, however my data frame has an additional 40,000ish rows that just say NA. Any idea what I can do to get rid of those rows?

Comment: `df2=df1[df1$Col2<0,]`

Comment: Okay that works, but for some reason I'm getting like 40,000 NA rows. Any idea what I can do to get rid of those?

Comment: `df2=df1[df1$Col2<0&!is.na(df1$Col2),]`

Comment: It'll need to be the other way around `df2=df1[!is.na(df1$Col2) & df1$Col2<0,]` that is you want to check for `NA` first.

Comment: Wen's second comment seems to work perfectly. Why would I need to check for NA first?

Comment: Also `df2 <- df1[which(df1$Col2<0),]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use subset

```
df2 <- subset(df1, subset = (Col2 <0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
                   "Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
                 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
                 1   -1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
                 1    NA   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
                 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
                 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can try `filter` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, Col2 < 0)
```